# Stale host addresses in Chrome

Tags: networking, browser, dns, xmlhttprequest

I'm tracking down a problem with our web application whereby a CNAME record swap of our site's domain is not picked up by Chrome for a long time, far exceeding the 300 second TTL of the DNS record. The remote address reported in Chrome inspector network tab for all XHR requests to our server is stale.

If I copy the XHR requests as curl and run it in the terminal then I can confirm it uses the IP addresses of the newly swapped-to domain, as expected. nslookup also reports the same addresses, so my local DNS cache appears to be fine.

In Chrome's netlog viewer (catapult) I can see our website's domain has an expired entry in the DNS cache with a TTL set to 10 seconds. I can also see requests made well after the entry expired, so it seems like Chrome isn't even checking the cache at all!

Curiously, when I flush the idle sockets on chrome://net-internals/#sockets then the host resolver does trigger as part of the SSL handshake and the new IP address is picked up.

My feeling is this is our web application is doing something to cause this weird behaviour. I've checked another one of our sites but cannot reproduce the problem. I thought we might be hanging on to a connection somewhere, but we're not using websockets and I can't see any other hanging network requests.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but yeah Chrome caches DNS resolution results, potentially longer than TTL. So your observation is correct. When I need to guarantee it updates the cache (e.g. when changing hosts file) I just restart  Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome caches 301 redirect infinitely in the local disk cache. I am not sure if this will solve your issue, but give it a try by clearing the local disk cache.

Here are the steps:

- Open **DevTools**
- On the **Network** tab check "**Disable cache**" checkbox
- Keep **Devtool** open and reload the page.

Check the IP & uncheck the **Disable cache** on the checkbox.